# Yum upgrade/update issue

Tags: git, gitlab, upgrade, yum

I am trying to automate my CICD pipeline on gitlab wherein, when creating rpm, it picks up base version from a file. But, then it adds the git commit id which is alpha numeric and pushes to yum repo.

yum is getting confused as the previous version to the latest version comparison fails since earlier versions(through SVN) had numbers as commit id (x(major).y(minor).z(patch)- <svn id which is numeric) but with git its alphanumeric. Is there any best practices on how to solve this please?

Thanks